# Android - Layout Reference through XMLs

Tags: java, android, xml

So I am attempting to setup an xml system through a test game I am creating.

initially, I will startup with the following onCreate method: http://pastie.org/8812144

Later in the code, within an onClick attached to the play button, I will then initialise the following code: http://pastie.org/pastes/8812147/text

Finally, I then will attempt an interaction with the ship to move it about with the following within onTouch/ACTION_MOVE: http://pastie.org/pastes/8812150/text

The actual coding of the ship works fine before I attempt to create the main screen and jiggle everything about. The play button works fine and the next layout is shown, however I am having trouble attempting to interact with the new layout. I am unsure of what the issue may be. My debugs show that the listener just isn't attached properly (as they don't show up when events should be called) but I am not sure exactly what is wrong with the way I have done it.

Thanks.

edit: here is the full code for your reference: http://pastie.org/8812278

Comment: Couldn't you put your code here, instead of forcing us to go back and forth from pastie?

Comment: Sure but it's longer this way: http://pastie.org/8812278

Answer (score 0):

Had to put the code in another activity and call it that way. the proper way. All is swell.